# Can't modify the context in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React, and I have a problem with the context :
I made a page as simple as possible, but the context never changes.
It must be a very little bug, but I compare with the tuto, and search on the Web but don't find the mistake...

Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  isLoggedIn: null,
  login: () => {
    throw new Error("login() not implemented yet");
  },
  logout: () => {
    throw new Error("logout() not implemented yet");
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      auth: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        login: this.login,
        logout: this.logout
      }
    }
  }

  login = () => {
    this.setState({
      auth: {
        isLoggedIn: true
        }
      })
  }

  logout = () => {
    this.setState({
      auth: {
        isLoggedIn: false
        }
      })
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.auth)
    console.log(this.context)
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={this.state.auth}>      
        <div className="App d-flex flex-column">
          { this.context.isLoggedIn ? (
                <div onClick={this.context.logout }>se déconnecter</div>
              )
             : (
                <div onClick={this.context.login }>Merci de vous connecter : "{ this.context.isLoggedIn}"</div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks,
Matche

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons your code isn't working:

- context is not being used correctly. Instead of trying to read `this.context`, use the hook `React.useContext()`
- you're attempting to use context in the same level component as the Provider. Context must be used in a *child* component of the provider.

I've refactored your code to make it work:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const Menu = () => {
  const { login, logout, isLoggedIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <div className="App d-flex flex-column">
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <div onClick={logout}>se déconnecter</div>
      ) : (
        <div onClick={login}>Merci de vous connecter : {isLoggedIn.toString()}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      auth: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        login: this.login,
        logout: this.logout
      }
    };
  }

  login = () => {
    this.setState({
      auth: {
        ...this.state.auth,
        isLoggedIn: true
      }
    });
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.setState({
      auth: {
        ...this.state.auth,
        isLoggedIn: false
      }
    });
  };
  render(props) {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={this.state.auth}>
        <Menu />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bhaskara-6g3zq?file=/src/App.js)

Further comments:

- you could simplify your code further by removing context entirely. You can just access the state values `logout, login, isLoggedIn` directly or pass them into a child component via props.
- context is just a useful way to pass a value directly from a parent component to a child component without needing to pass it through every component between them via props. Context is not a replacement for state.
- Component `<App>` could be simplified even further than it has above by converting it into a functional component that uses `useState` hook.

Good luck with your learning

Comment: Thanks for your two answers and your advices ro-milton and @jcklopp, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confusing state with context?  You generally use context only when the same data needs to be used by many different components.  Using context can make component reuse more difficult, so use with caution;)  For state based switching try something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  isLoggedIn: null,
  login: () => {
    throw new Error("login() not implemented yet");
  },
  logout: () => {
    throw new Error("logout() not implemented yet");
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      auth: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        login: this.login,
        logout: this.logout
      }
    }
  }

  login = () => {
    this.setState({
      auth: {
        isLoggedIn: true
        }
      })
  }

  logout = () => {
    this.setState({
      auth: {
        isLoggedIn: false
        }
      })
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.auth)
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={this.state.auth}>      
        <div className="App d-flex flex-column">
          { this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
                <div onClick={this.state.logout }>se déconnecter</div>
              )
             : (
                <div onClick={this.state.login }>Merci de vous connecter : "{ this.state.isLoggedIn}"</div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```